# Rendering in MarkedJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, javascript-marked

I have this problem where it dosent render my code properly for some odd reason, and ill show you my code. So here is my code from the Controller(AngularJS) :

```
$scope.$watch('creatorValue', function(current, original) {
          var htmlVal = document.getElementById('creatorValue').innerHTML;
          console.log(original);
           htmlVal = marked(original);
});
```

And here is a Minimal HTML:

```
<div class="topic-sentence">
        <p class="topic-text" id="creatorValue">{{creatorValue}}</p>
</div>
```

Well as you can see i logged the original value and it came up with the correct result:
[image]

Well yeah, it logs the correct thing.... Then It Must Show the right display right?
[image]

Nope as you can see above, all the code is in one line, and there is nothing "marked". If you guys want to see more code, let me know in the comments below. Help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, you have not put the marked content back to the DOM. This should work, please try.

```
$scope.$watch('creatorValue', function(current, original) {          
    document.getElementById('creatorValue').innerHTML = marked(original);
});
```

Comment: Yup tried $scope.creatorValue with ng-bind-html rigth after i asked the question and i got it then. Your way is a diffrent approach than mine, but still acomplishes the same goal. Thanks for your help anways, im sure this will help many users.